# Add views dynamically depending on the screen size in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, view, screen-size

I want to add views dynamically (horizontal or vertical) in a row. Each view has a fixed size and fixed padding. **How do I decide how many views I can add dynamically depending on the device screen size.** For example, smaller phones or with mdpi might have lesser number of views added compared to xhdpi devices.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to add the views dynamically or is this a pre-requisite of the design? If you just want things to be adjusted according to screen size, create different layouts for each logical screen density.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9371617/1210260

Comment: Hey dcanh121 have you got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways.

First, you can check the size of your container by calling getWidth() and getHeight()
In your view you can override onMeasure()

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

If you have different XML layouts based on the screen size, you can check to see what one of them loaded and act accordingly.

Comment: I have only one layout file, say empty LinearLayout. I will then add views dynamically to this layout.

Comment: Assuming that your View is set to fill_parent, why don't you just call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight() and see what you are working with.

Comment: I will have my layout set to fill_parent. I cannot add more than one view view to the layout if the view is set to fill_parent

Comment: ok. But you can still get a handle on the view's parent and do the same thing no?

Comment: I am not asking how to add the view. I am asking, how to decide how many views should be added depending on the device (mdpi or hdpi), because on some devices only 4 views and others 5 views can be shown.

Comment: If my example doesn't work for you, the only thing I can suggest is creating an integer.xml with the same variable name and different values for each dpi bin and see what the value is once your program is running. It's kinda like enumerating all of your choices.

Comment: Because I don't know how many fit in each dpi, and hardcoding isn't a good idea, I figured out that I should write some logic similar to Google I/O app (dashboard).